Crop from Left to Right and Top to Bottom (Not X and Y)
What tools can crop images from left to right and top to bottom? I don't want to crop by setting numbers for X and Y. To be specific, I want something like this.

What software are you using?

I can't see the logic in choosing an aspect ratio and at the same time specifying a number of pixels to remove from each side. How would that work? What if you make the shown settings and the input image is for example 2000x2000px?

I was using MoviePrint.

Here's the thing, Wolff. When I selected the aspect ratio, it cropped 60 pixels for the top and bottom of the images. I want a software that can do that to multiple images at once.

A command line app like ImageMagick is probably the way to go

What should the command be?

Your dialog is mathematematically overconstrained. This means that there is a potenttially contradiction in your dialog. Anyway read https://superuser.com/questions/1161340/how-to-crop-an-image-using-imagemagick-from-the-command-line#1161341
